# VBA pasting into column IF date in cell x equal the date in column y

Tags: html, vba, excel, date

Title says it all really.

I have a date in a tab called "Value" with the value of last work day in the previous month. I then want to see if this date in in the column B of another tab, if so i would like to paste certain information (e.g. cell a1 value) into column D where the row equals the date.

example so if the date in cell a1 (tab1) is found in tab2 column b paste the information from tab1 cell b1 into the same row where the date was found.

My Code which i tried so you can see what im doing is:

```
   'formula to paste information from cell into correct column in correct tab,

    daterow = Application.Match(CLng(Worksheets("Value").Range("D19")), 
    Worksheets("Regional Day Breakdown Sales").Columns("B"), 0)
    If Not IsError(daterow) Then
        Worksheets("Regional Day Breakdown Sales").Cells(daterow, "F").Value = 
    ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value
        Else
        MsgBox ("Date not in range")
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `daterow`? And it is a good idea to copy and paste the code from your VBEditor to SO. E.g. this should be on one line - `Worksheets("Regional Day Breakdown Sales").Cells(daterow, "F").Value = 
    ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value`

Comment: Dim daterow As Variant  
if i swap the "Value".Range bit for date, this works with today's date but i wanted to swap that for the date in cell D19 (value tab) so just swapped it, honestly im not good with VBA so normally just find the code and edit it, just had a bit of a problem editing this one :(

Comment: Do you get an error anywhere? What is the error?

Comment: Does the above code error? Does it not error but not do what you need? What is it doing? Remember, we can't see your data/workbook so you need to provide a little more information.

Comment: error message is: type 13 mismatch - i presume because i amended the code incorrectly so this one works but when i swap "date" for new target date it doesn't play ball! 

Code:

Comment: What is in D19? And please don't code in comments - as you can see it's not readable.

Comment: d19 is the date in the format 31/07/2018  (but this is based on a formula so will always be equal to the last working day of the prior month) NOT text format so should match that in Column B in my other tab

Comment: So what is the value of daterow when it errors? Step through your code.

Comment: apologies for the confusion probably worded question badly - i solved my problem with solution below, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was being an idiot just needed to remove the Clng too, thanks for the help

a)

```
  daterow = Application.Match(Worksheets("Value").Range("D17"), Worksheets("Regional 
Day Breakdown Sales").Columns("B"), 0)
If Not IsError(daterow) Then
    Worksheets("Regional Day Breakdown Sales").Cells(daterow, "F").Value = 
ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value
    Else
    MsgBox ("Date not in range")
End If
```